# Magento 2 checkout shipping rates collection

Tags: magento, knockout.js, magento2

I'm trying to trigger shipping rates recollection on checkout via 3d party JS code, not Knockout. What's the best way to trigger it?

Now I've replaced template onepage.phtml with custom one and trying this approach, but it doesn't work:

```
    require([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
    ], function($, quote) {
        $('#target').on('click', function(e) {
            console.log(quote.shippingAddress(quote.shippingAddress()));
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, guys. Here is the solution:

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/customer-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/new-address',
], function($, quote, shippingService, rateRegistry, customerAddressProcessor, newAddressProcessor) {
    $('#target').on('click', function(e) {
        var address = quote.shippingAddress();
        // clearing cached rates to retrieve new ones
        rateRegistry.set(address.getCacheKey(), null);
        var type = quote.shippingAddress().getType();
        if (type) {
            customerAddressProcessor.getRates(address);
        } else {
            newAddressProcessor.getRates(address);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: where i should add the js script to work on checkout page?

Comment: but not getting refreshed address.

Comment: @c0rewell,for this step(rateRegistry.set(address.getCacheKey(), null);) it's giving error

Answer (score 0):

i already tried @c0rewell way

1. Company_Modulename/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

> ```
> var config = {
>     map: {
>         '*': {
>             company: 'Company_Modulename/js/myjs'
>         }
>     }
> };
> ```

2. Company_Modulename/view/frontend/web/js/myjs.js

```js
require([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/customer-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/new-address',
], function($, quote, shippingService, rateRegistry, customerAddressProcessor, newAddressProcessor) {
    $('div[name="shippingAddress.city"] select[name="city2"]').live('change', function(e) {
        var address = quote.shippingAddress();
        // clearing cached rates to retrieve new ones
        
  rateRegistry.set(address.getCacheKey(), null);
  
        var type = quote.shippingAddress().getType();
        if (type) {
            customerAddressProcessor.getRates(address);
        } else {
            newAddressProcessor.getRates(address);
        }
    });
});
```

above sciprt successfully force refresh the shipping cost, but the loading takeing forever

error from console

```
resource-url-manager.js:35 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getQuoteId' of undefined
at Object.getUrlForEstimationShippingMethodsByAddressId (resource-url-manager.js:35)
at Object.getRates (customer-address.js:26)
at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (xongkir.js:17)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js:4624)
at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4292)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ansyori 
I have managed to run the estimat-shipping-methods by modifying code like below

```
require([
'jquery',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/customer-address',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/new-address',
], function($, quote, shippingService, rateRegistry, 
  customerAddressProcessor, newAddressProcessor) {
$('div[name="shippingAddress.city"] select[name="city2"]').live('change', function(e) {
    var address = quote.shippingAddress();
    // clearing cached rates to retrieve new ones

    rateRegistry.set(address.getCacheKey(), null);

    var type = quote.shippingAddress().getType();
    if (type == 'new-customer-address') {
                newAddressProcessor.getRates(address);
            }
});
});
```